# Iterate Over Controls in Repeater

Tags: asp.net

I have a bit of code that determine whether or not a control (within a repeater) should be visible or not and I want to call this on Page_Load but I can't seem to get the Controls inside a repeater.

```
<asp:Repeater ID="repreat" runat="server" >
        <HeaderTemplate>
            <asp:PlaceHolder runat="server" ID="thActivePrimary">Blah</asp:PlaceHolder>
            <asp:PlaceHolder runat="server" ID="PlaceHolder1">Blah</asp:PlaceHolder>
        </HeaderTemplate>
        <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:PlaceHolder runat="server" ID="trActivePrimary">Blah</asp:PlaceHolder>
            <asp:PlaceHolder runat="server" ID="thActivePrimary2">Blah</asp:PlaceHolder>
        </ItemTemplate>              
</asp:Repeater>
```

repreat.Controls is always empty.

How do I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The controls are not created at page load, They are created when databind is called. If you want to access each item as they are created have a look at the DataBound event of the repeater.

Or bind the visible attribute to your datasource

Answer (score 3):

```
    foreach (RepeaterItem ri in repeat.Items)
         ri.FindControl("thActivePrimary").Visible = false;
```

This should work